# Getting content security policy error while loading react component in lightning:container

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, csp, lightning-container

I am importing a react component from static resource in lightning container, that component itself communicates with AWS. When I load this component in lightning:container, I am getting below errors:
[image]

Code of my aura app:

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL">   
    <lightning:container aura:id="jsApp" src="{!$Resource.abc + '/index.html'}" onmessage="{!c.handleMessage}"
            onerror="{!c.handleError}"/>
</aura:application>
```

The endpoint to which it communicates is already added in CSP list with connect src as true and also in Trusted sites under session settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved by some cleanup steps in the org:

1. Deselected unneeded directives for existing trusted sites.
2. Removed all unused trusted sites for these contexts.